# How to have RDP work right after rebooting?

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop

I have a Windows machine which I run headless (no monitor or keyboard). I control it by Remote Desktop. But whenever it reboots (for Windows updates and such), the RDP won't work until I log in physically. It's annoying; any way to have the RDP client (or whatever is necessary to enable remote login) start immediately on boot-up? Another option is to have it log me in as a user automatically, and I may do that (the computer is in my home and so under physical control) but it's not ideal - would be safer I guess to just have it run RDP and force the user to present credentials, rather than simply logging in into an account. How to make that happen?

Comment: This can be achieved with Teamviewer. But i'm not sure acout RDP. I believe you'll need to have the user account automatically login.

Comment: @NiallJones: The odd thing about this problem is that RDP always performs the login _on its own_ (unlike Teamviewer/VNC/etc, which have to use an existing login).

Comment: @grawity you're right. I didn't think of that.

Comment: The problem isn't with RDP. It is always available automatically... In fact, it's possible to connect via RDP to a machine *before* logon is possible. It's likely that logging in at the console is changing something with your network connectivity, ie connecting you to a user-based 802.1x authenticated network, or loading an internet filtering application etc. What do you have on the machine that's blocking inbound connections until you logon?

Comment: You should be able to login to the console rather than on user level, which is the failsafe way. Connect to your ip address and append /admin. For example: server address: `192.168.0.1 /admin`

Comment: > Connect to your ip address and append /admin. For example: server address: 192.168.0.1 /admin     -         ah, so in the RDP client application, where it asks me for the IP address of the host, I can append /admin and it will work even if no one logged on yet after a reboot?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, connecting my Macbook to Windows 10 RDP. After I turned on the Windows machine, I first needed to login into it, before I could activate the RDP connection (using the same account).

After disabling the option "Allow connections only from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication (recommended)" from the advanced RDP settings in Windows, the problem was resolved.

Note: when using Jump Desktop as a client, also disable the "Use Network Level Authentication" setting in the client configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Set the service "Remote Desktop Services" startup type to automatic ?

For Automatic Login you can set directly in the registry:

Navigate to or create this folder:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

Create 3 REG_SZ keys

```
 - AutoAdminLogon set to 1
 - DefaultUserName set to <username>
 - DefaultPassword set to <password>
```

You may need `DefaultDomainName` set if it's on a domain.

If you have enterprise you can set these in Group Policy objects here:

```
Computer Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry
```